# Keep an OCaml value alive forever off heap / intentionally leak OCaml value

Tags: c, ocaml

What do you need to do to allocate an immortal OCaml object off-heap in a C function? In particular, how do you make an OCaml value that looks to the runtime like a global variable in OCaml source code would.

Here is my attempt at producing an intentionally broken program that neglects to register a value as a GC root.

Here's the OCaml source file driving everything.

```
(* immortal_string.ml *)

external make_string : string -> unit = "make_string"
external get_string : unit -> string = "get_string"

let () = make_string "a"
let () = Gc.full_major ()
let () = Printf.printf "%s\n" (get_string ())
```

And the C implementation. There are probably better ways to do this than using `0` as a sentinel value and a function static, but I think the intent is clear. Note that multiple calls to `make_string` will clobber the value that was originally there, but that's okay. I want the memory pointed to by old values to be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

```
// lib_immortal_string.c

#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
#include <caml/memory.h>
#include <caml/alloc.h>

value *storage(void) {
    // BAD! we haven't registered this thing
    // as a GC root. No clue how you do that.
    static value data = 0; // sentinel, will never be valid OCaml value
    if (data == 0) {
        data = caml_copy_string("");
    }
    return &data;
}

CAMLprim value
make_string(value ml_string) {
    CAMLparam1(ml_string);
    *storage() = ml_string;
    CAMLreturn(Val_unit);
}

CAMLprim value
get_string(value ml_unit) {
    CAMLparam1(ml_unit);
    CAMLreturn(*storage());
}
```

I was expecting this program to segfault since there's nothing obvious keeping `data` in the `storage` function alive. `data` is not global and isn't on the stack. However, the program *appears* to run without reclaiming the string.

```
$ ocamlopt immortal_string.ml lib_immortal_string.c
./a.out
a
```

So my question is, what is the proper way to make a global OCaml value / off-heap thing? And, furthermore, why does the above program appear to work instead of crashing?

Comment: Are string literals even allocated on the heap? I imagine the "a" is simply in the programs data section and not managed dynamically at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's virtually no reuse of memory going on in your small program, so I guess the string  "a" still looks the same after the garbage collection, even if it's not referenced by anything.

If you call GC every time, it just returns things to a well-ordered state. It would be better to let the GC happen normally, which will run through many more possible memory states.

You also have to do some looping to give it time to fail.

A slightly modified version of your code does in fact segfault for me:

```
external make_string : string -> unit = "make_string"
external get_string : unit -> string = "get_string"

let () =
    while true do
        let a = String.make (1024 * 1024) 'a' in
        make_string a;
        let b = String.make (1024 * 1024) 'b' in
        Printf.printf "%s %s\n" (get_string ()) b
    done
```

The way to mark a value as a GC root is with `caml_register_global_root`

```
caml_register_global_root(&data);
```

Just as you expected, if I call this under `if (data == 0) {` there is no segfault.

This is documented in [Section 19.5 of the OCaml manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.05/intfc.html#sec423).

Comment: ProTip: it is more efficient to use `caml_register_generational_global_root` provided that you're taking the responsibility to modify the value only via the `caml_modify_generational_global_root` function.

Comment: Yes, by all means read Section 19.5 if you're going to use these constructs in real code :-)

Comment: Does marking the root as global prevent the GC from moving it?

Comment: The thing that is marked is `data` (in this example). Obviously it can't be moved itself. The contents of `data` (the OCaml value) might easily be changed. So I think the short answer is no.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield ... so when a compaction occurs, can the contents of `data` in C either a) become dangling or b) get changed by the OCaml runtime? `b` seems tolerable, but `a` seems scary.

Comment: The contents of `data` will be changed, yes. The contents will not become dangling! That's the point of declaring `data` as a GC root. The GC will keep the value in `data` up to date with the latest state of the heap as objects are moved around etc.

Comment: Note that implies that you can not read out data after releasing the runtime lock and have to read out data again every time the GC might have run (like after allocating a new ocaml value). Not in this simple example but beware of it when you write more complex functions.

Comment: (Threading issues are discussed in [Section 19.11 of the OCaml manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.05/intfc.html#sec453).)